# How to get control and pass the values in textbox in a webpage automatically

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

i wants to automatically load the url and get the control of signin button and pass the value to the text using c# in visual studio.i have tried using htmlagilitypack for getting the control and for passing the values in a textbox, i have used selenium webdriver. iam able to load the url and not able to get the control of signin button and not able to pass the value in textbox. could someone help me in this case i was stuck with past one week.i have attached the sample code i have tried.

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;   

namespace HtmlAgilityPackTest
{​​​​​
    class Program
    {​​​​​
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {​​​​​
            //string driver = "Email";
            string itext = "Sign In";
            //string email = "Email";
            //IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
            var uri = "https://developer.servicenow.com";
            var psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.UseShellExecute = true;
            psi.FileName = uri;

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
            //Thread.Sleep(3000);
            var func = string.Format(@"document.getElementsByClass('dps-button-label').innerText = '{​​​​​0}​​​​​';",itext);

            //Thread.Sleep(3000);
                IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
                IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("form-control input-box username-box"));

                element.SendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

your button is in lot shadowRoot: you have to do this function to click on signin button:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ExpectedConditions = SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions;

:
:
:
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Url = "https://developer.servicenow.com";
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        var query = "return document.querySelector('dps-app').shadowRoot";
        query += ".querySelector('dps-navigation-header').shadowRoot";
        query += ".querySelector('dps-login').shadowRoot";
        query += ".querySelector('dps-button')";
        IWebElement elt = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript(query);
        elt.Click();
           
        # you have to install SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers nugget package fo that
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("username"))).SendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("usernameSubmitButton"))).Click();

        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("username"))).SendKeys("email@toto.fr");
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("usernameSubmitButton"))).Click();
        var but = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("submitButton")));
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("password");
        but.Click();
```

before executing this code, wait 3 or 5 sec to be sure the page html is loaded completely

so i havent EDGE, i have tested with firefox

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but i need it using c# i tried this code but this shows an error and i have used
IWebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.Name("dps-button-label")); but it didnt capture signin button and click on it, can i get an answer in this case using c#?

Comment: it was C#, i have fixed some typo error

Comment: i have done a little video to see the result https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q8y5_WcJ830k-JFgcgRcbh3PuwLRZNES/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks much, able to get the signin control and pass the email id value to the text and not able to pass the value for password field and click on signin button atlast i tried this code but it shows (element not interactable) exception, i have attached the code that i have tried, could someone help me in this case. (IWebElement pas1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
            pas1.SendKeys("xxxxx");
            IWebElement ele3 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("submitButton"));
            ele3.Click();)

Comment: Thanks much frenchy, atlast for getting the control of start building i tried using this but it shows exception i have attached the line that i have i have modified.kindly help me(IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        var query = "return document.querySelector('dps-app').shadowRoot";
        query += ".querySelector('dps-home-auth-quebec').shadowRoot"; q       query += ".querySelector('dps-home-section-content -header').shadowRoot";
        query += ".querySelector('cta-button')";
        IWebElement elt = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript(query);
        elt.Click();)

Comment: sorry but your problem is after the authorization email/password right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238956/discussion-between-lydia-sahayam-and-frenchy).